# Using lapply to a list of data frames so that column names are alphabetical for binding together?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, rbind

I have a list of about 20 data frames that I would like to combine into 1 big dataframe the problem being some of the column orders in some of the dataframes do not match (the names do the order just does not)

I am trying to apply a: order colnames too all of the dataframes so they are all alphabetical and will be able to rbind them all together.

I am fairly new and may be going about it  the wrong way. Any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: You can `rbind()` data frames together even if the columns aren't in the same order. `rbind(data.frame(a = 1, b = 2), data.frame(b = 2, a = 1))`.

Comment: Ahh I was not aware of this! But I have 20+ columns and 20+ dataframes is there a way where I don't have to assign stuff? That's why I was thinking of making everything in the same order before the binding

Comment: What do you mean assign stuff? The order will be kept the same as the order in the first data frame.

Comment: Sorry maybe I misunderstood. Using this: rbind(data.frame(a = 1, b = 2), data.frame(b = 2, a = 1)) I am a little confused as to how I can apply this my list of 20 dataframes should I be using lapply?

Comment: Try `do.call(rbind, my_list)`

Answer (score 0):

A fairly easy way of doing this is by using `dplyr::bind_rows`

```
lst <- list(
  data.frame(a = 'A1', b = 'B1', c = 'C1'), 
  data.frame(a = 'A2', c = 'C2', b = 'B2'), 
  data.frame(c = 'C3', b = 'B3', a = 'A3')
)

dplyr::bind_rows(lst)
```

which yields

```
   a  b  c
1 A1 B1 C1
2 A2 B2 C2
3 A3 B3 C3
```